# Setting up VirtualHost - All Point to same host

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I am trying to set my domain yfcclub.ga to folder `/var/www/yfc` while leave localhost and all other domains to `/var/www/html` in ubuntu.
My vhosts.cof file is:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/www/html/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/html/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost yfcclub.ml:80>
        ServerName yfcclub.ml        
        ServerAdmin webmaster@yfcclub.ml
        DocumentRoot /var/www/yfc

        <Directory /var/www/yfc>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog /var/www/yfc/.errors/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/yfc/.errors/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

> But, all domains and localhost point to `var/www/yfc` folder. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need named virtual hosts enabled ..  before you try using this logic. Do you have it? `NameVirtualHost *:80`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Change "VirtualHost" record.

<VirtualHost *:80>
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yfcclub.ml        
    ServerAdmin webmaster@yfcclub.ml
    DocumentRoot /var/www/yfc

    <Directory /var/www/yfc>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog /var/www/yfc/.errors/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/yfc/.errors/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You mean replace `_default_` with `*`?

Comment: 1. Remove #(comment) NameVirtualHost *:80 in conf file apache2 (httpd)

Comment: 2. Change <VirtualHost yfcclub.ml:80> --><VirtualHost *:80>

Comment: 3. Domain yfcclub.ml will take content for DocumentRoot /var/www/yfc

Comment: 4. All domains will take default page Apache